# Is it possible to configure Gulp Livereload for Django?

Tags: python, django, gulp, gulp-livereload

I would like to use **gulp-liveReload with Django**, is it possible? I have read that there is an alternative for Grunt, but I would prefer work with Gulp, it is easier for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote up how to do it in a recent blog post here:

http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/oct/21/ultimate-front-end-development-setup/

Basically you just need to write gulp tasks that watch what files you want to trigger livereloads, so for me that's templates:

```
/* Trigger a live reload on any Django template changes */
gulp.watch('**/templates/**').on('change', livereload.changed);
```

But you could also trigger it on models.py, views.py, or anything else you want really.

Comment: I'm using this and it works fine for CSS file changes, etc., but not templates. The only way it works with templates is if I touch or make changes to a `.py` file and then change a template. Did you run into this problem or is it working as-is for you somehow?

Comment: Hi Mike, apologies I had a typo in the above it should be '**/templates/**' not what I originally had which is '**/templates/*'. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

have you try this [django-livereload](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-livereload) ?

Comment: No, I haven't try it. Finally I have installed gulp-livereload and it works ;). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also was struggling to find an answer howto to start a django server and get the browser live reloading working at the same time, however it turned out that it is easy to achieve (even when working cross platform on windows and linux):

```
//jshint node:true
'use strict';

var gulp          = require('gulp'),
    ....
    gutil         = require('gulp-util');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

var serverUrl = 'localhost:8000';

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var isProd = gutil.env.type === 'prod';

....
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return sass(sources.sass, {
    compass: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    style: isProd ? 'compressed': 'expanded',
  })
  ....
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(targets.css))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
....

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(sources.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(sources.pug, ['html'])
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch(sources.ts, ['typescript'])
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);

  // update browser on python change
  gulp.watch('website/**/*.py')
    .on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


// start django server
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform);
  var cmd =  '. venv/bin/activate && PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ';

  if (isWin) { //for Windows
    cmd = 'venv\\Scripts\\activate.bat && set PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 && ';
  }

  var proc = exec(cmd + 'python manage.py runserver ' + serverUrl);
  proc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    process.stdout.write(data);
  });

  proc.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    process.stdout.write(data);
  });
});


// start livereload
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['typescript', 'html', 'sass', 'webserver'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
      proxy: serverUrl,
      port: 8080,
      reloadDelay: 300,
      reloadDebounce: 500
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you are talking about the static assets (stuff under `static`) in your django project.

The key step is to make the pages served by `python manage.py runserver` be aware of changes from the `livereload server` (usually implemented by `tiny-lr`)

A simple way to do so is to inject the following code to your `base.html` (assuming it as the parent template for the rest of html templates in `django` project)

```
# views.py
from django.conf import settings
# other imports ...
def index(request):
    ctx = {'debug': settings.DEBUG, }
    # other context setup...
    return render(request, 'index.html', ctx)

# other views' definitions...

<!-- base.html -->
{% if debug %}
    <!-- 
         assuming your livereload server runs at localhost:35729 
                                         (default host:port for livereload )
    -->
    <script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
{% endif %}

// gulpfile.js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    coffee = require('gulp-coffee'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    debug = require('gulp-debug'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch');

// other tasks definitions...

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    livereload.listen();    // starts a tiny-lr server, 
                            // default livereload server port is 35729
    gulp.src('static/src/**/*.coffee')
        .pipe(watch('static/src/**/*.coffee'))
        .pipe(coffee())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist'))
        .pipe(livereload()); // send a signal to tiny-lr server 
                             // to make the page with livereload.js 
                             // to perform a reload action
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried [Frank Wile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27974426/996114), but I was having issues with it. The only way it worked for me with templates is if I saved a `.py` file and then made a change to a template.

I extended Frank's approach with a function that essentially `touch`es a `.py` file before calling `livereload.changed()`:

```
function touchPy() {
    gulp.src(appName + '/__init__.py')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(appName));
}

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();

    // Changes to .css files works fine w/ Frank's approach
    gulp.watch(paths.static).on('change', livereload.changed);

    // Changes to .html files don't trigger a runserver refresh w/o touching a .py file 
    gulp.watch(paths.templates).on('change', function(file) {
        touchPy();
        livereload.changed(file);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://127.0.0.1:32700/livereload.js" />
```

to django main template. See http://argskwargs.io/blog/javascript/django-typescript-gulp-part-three/ . This is example for js and css files:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var gzip_options = {
    threshold: '1kb',
    gzipOptions: {
        level: 9
    }
};

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('static/css/*.css')
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src('static/js/*.js')
        .pipe(livereload());
});

/* Watch Files For Changes */
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen(32700);
    gulp.watch('static/css/*.css', ['css']);
    gulp.watch('static/js/*.js', ['js']);

    gulp.watch('static/css/*', 'static/js/*').on('change', livereload.changed);
});

gulp.task('default', ['css', 'js', 'watch']);
```